Expo - How to build localy using my keystore with prebuild
I don't want to use EAS for now.
I rewrote my existing app with Expo.
I couldn't find in the Expo documentation how to use my existing keystore when using the prebuild functionality. Meaning that my android folder is generated by Expo. According the the doc, the "credentials.json" file seams to be for EAS only.
Anyone have found a solution for this ?
Thx a lot.
